# Unable to connect to Pi4 Headless after installing TOR

Tags: pi-4, headless

I installed TOR on my headless Pi4. Everything looks to be working fine.
But i can no more access to Pi through VNC as usual. Even after adding ssh and wpa_supplicant files as usual. Ethernet cable is unplugged of course. And Samba is not installed on my Pi. Do you think there is a way to solve this ?
Thanks.

Comment: i think yes ... any problem can be solved .... is that all you wanted to know?

Comment: Hi jsotola, yes i would like to know how can i get back my Pi4 to work headless again. I'd prefer to not format my sd card because i will loose then several files. Thank you.